# How to build a user level program in parallel with building Linux kernel

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a set of kernel source files in ~linux/fs/wrapfs/. Besides, there is also a source file present for a user level program. I want to build that user level program while the kernel gets compiled by running "make" in ~/linux folder i.e in the top level kernel directory.

So, I tried adding following in ~/linux/fs/wrapfs/Makefile:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += prog    
prog:
    gcc -Wall -Werror prog.c -o prog -lssl -lcrypto
```

But, then everytime I do "make" in ~/linux, I get following error:

```
gcc: prog: No such file or directory
```

I then tried changing it to following but nothing helped:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += prog
all:
    gcc -Wall -Werror prog.c -o prog -lssl -lcrypto

EXTRA_CFLAGS += prog
prog:
    gcc -Wall -Werror ./fs/wrapfs/prog.c -o ./fs/wrapfs/prog -lssl -lcrypto
```

Please suggest how can this be solved.

Comment: It could be a bug inside your `Makefile`; you might consider using `remake` and running `remake -x`

Answer (score 1):

You should not be trying to pass `prog` in CFLAGS, extra or otherwise.

Comment: so can you please suggest how can I achieve my required goal.